# On understanding tradeoffs associated with pipeline depth

Tags: computer-architecture, vlsi, pipeline

In Weste and Harris's *CMOS VLSI Design*, they write the following in the context of a discussion about how different levels of design abstraction interact but, to be clear, my question is about the specific claims made and so it's more of a computer organization question:

> Deeper pipelines allow higher frequencies but consume more power and lead to greater performance penalties when operations early in the pipe- line are dependent on those late in the pipeline. Many functions have various logic and circuit designs trading speed for area, power, and design effort.

My questions are listed below (and in brackets I have put my best guess to show that I have thought about each):

(1) What is meant by deeper pipelines?

(Does this mean more pipeline stages?)

(2) Why do they allow for higher clock frequencies

(Is this because the combinational circuits between each stage are smaller and therefore we have less propagation delay, and so need less cycle time before each pipeline register needs to setup?)

(3) Given a deeper pipeline, why does it follow that they use more power?

(Is this because of the higher frequency, or is it that even at the same frequency as a less deep pipeline they will tend to use more energy because they are clocked into extra registers which switch, costing dynamic power?)

(4) Why does a less deep pipeline not have the same performance issues if there are dependencies between operations in the pipeline?

(Not really sure at all here. Is it that in a deeper pipeline the dependant operation would have to idle or something? Don’t we have pass back strategies to avoid this? So why does depth of pipeline matter)?

Comment: All your suppositions are exactly right. Avoiding the whole pipeline idling when certain branches are taken, is an area of active improvement (branch "prediction"). But in general, a CPUs number of stages is rather limited because of branches. VLSI for more predictable workloads can have more stages.

Comment: (1) deeper means more. (2) Because they are shallower, which means shorter propagation delays. (3) More parallel stages in operation each clock and shorter clock periods. (4) Confusing question. Not sure how to address it.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! With regard to (4) the question is basically why does a deeper pipeline experience performance issues when we have dependent instructions whereas a shallower pipeline does not? @periblepsis

Comment: @EE18 When more is performed within a stage, there are fewer reasons that a stage would need to wait/stall. Taken to the extreme, only 1 stage, everything gets done and there's no reason for RISC to stall. I had the good fortune to have the undivided attention of Dr. Hennessey for two partial consecutive days in 1986. The venerable MIPS R2000, [with 5 stages](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/sp04/OldLectures/week14.pdf), simply didn't allow reasons to stall. So one doesn't have to stall with more stages. One can just ignore the hazards and leave it to code to worry over. Lot to think on.

Comment: This makes a great deal of sense, thank you for clarifying! As always, I invite you to just copy-paste that as an answer if you'd like, but as always I understand you don't mind either way :) thanks again for your help! @periblepsis

Comment: @EE18 Yeah. It's enough for me that you have at least some of what you'd wanted. The site wants traffic driven to it so they want the kind of answers that do that. Which take work. Most of the answers are short and may only achieve that goal through their sheer volume as opposed to quality. In any case, the site's interest isn't aligned with mine, except occasionally. In this case, I'm good. Also, leaving it wide open may attract for the site answers it would want to see because of the lower competition for getting selected. Wouldn't want to harm that! ;)

Comment: Touche! Thanks again at any rate :) @periblepsis